# Switching between float and double precision at compile time

Tags: c++, floating-point-precision, double-precision

Where should I look at if I want to switch between float and double precision at compile time. Its like, if user wants everything in float instead of double precision how I can maintain this flexibility? In other words, how should I define a variable that could be either float or double precision conditionally?

Comment: At compile time or run time?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If it is OK to make the switch at compile time, a simple `typedef` would do:

```
#ifdef USE_DOUBLES
typedef double user_data_t;
#else
typedef float user_data_t;
#endif
```

Use `user_data_t` in your code, and set `USE_DOUBLES` if you want `doubles` at compile time:

```
g++ -DUSE_DOUBLES=1 myprogram.cpp
```

Comment: Compile both copies, slap a shell script redirector in front, and viola!

Comment: @Shibli There are several ways. Using `-D...` compiler option works for many UNIX compilers. On Windows you can set use `/D`, or add `USE_DOUBLES` to the list of preprocessor definitions in the properties of your C/C++ project.

Comment: I put `-DUSE_DOUBLES=1` into my make file directly and checked the type of a variable which was float. So, how can use this for a make file?

Comment: @Shibli How did you check the type of the variable? You declared all your variables that must change between `float` and `double` as `user_data_t`, right?

Comment: I declared a new variable as `user_data_t temp` then checked the type as `cout << typeid(temp).name();` then it gave `f`.

Comment: @Shibli I just tried what you did: I compiled a small program ([link to pastebin](http://pastebin.com/bZNkW6Bq)) with `g++ -DUSE_DOUBLES=1 x.cpp` command, and got a `d`; when I compiled with `g++ x.cpp`, I got an `f`.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly how you intent to use the data, it's hard to recommend the correct solution.

Have a look at the **union** date type.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dxy4b7b(v=VS.80).aspx

**Templates** would also be a viable option depending on the usage.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y097fkab.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I prefer not to have `#define`s in my code.

I would have two different headers with two different `typedef`s, and allow build options to choose which header is included.