# How to easily switch between single and double precision in CUDA?

Tags: c, cuda, gpgpu, precision

When debugging developing and debugging, I would like to run my code with double precision. However, once I know it's working, I'd like the option to run my code using single precision (i.e. `float`s) only. So I'd like to be able to easily switch between these precisions without a large rewrite of code. I was thinking of some `#define` flag like

```
#define PRECISION double
...

thrust::device_vector<PRECISION> myVec;
```

but the compiler doesn't seem to like that. Any ideas on how to implement this?

I know [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511910/switching-between-float-and-double-precision-at-compile-time?rq=1) is very similar in that it solves the problem with compiler flags. But I was hoping to be able to directly set a flag directly from within my source code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
#ifdef MY_USE_DOUBLE_PRECISION
typedef double Real;
#else
typedef float Real;
#endif

....

thrust::device_vector<Real> myVec;
```

using `MY_USE_DOUBLE_PRECISION` to control the definition of the floating point type `Real`. If you have your own kernels you can also use `Real` in place of either `float` or `double` ie. :

```
__global__ void kernel (Real *input, Real *output)
{
   ...
}
```

If you want to have *both* single and double precision versions of the kernel code compiled and select which one to use outside of the compilation unit where they are defined (in a library, for example), you can template the kernel:

```
 template<typename T>
__global__ void kernel (T *input, T *output)
{
   ...
}

template __global__ void kernel<float>(float *, float *);
template __global__ void kernel<double>(double *, double *);
```

and then in another source file

```
#ifdef MY_USE_DOUBLE_PRECISION
typedef double Real;
#else
typedef float Real;
#endif

....

kernel<Real><<<griddim, blockdim>>>(....);
```