# Flexibly set floating point number precision at compile time

Tags: c++, precision

I have a C++ program that can be compiled for single or double precision floating point numbers. Similar as explained here ([Switching between float and double precision at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511910/switching-between-float-and-double-precision-at-compile-time)), I have a header file which defines:

`typedef double dtype`

or:

`typedef float dtype`

depending on whether single or double precision is required by the user. When declaring variables and arrays I always use the data type `dtype`, so the correct precision is used throughout the code.

My question is how can I, in a similar fashion, set the data type of hard-coded numbers in the code, like for instance in this example:

`dtype var1 = min(var0, 3.65)`

As far as I know, 3.65 is by default double precision and will be single precision if I write:

`dtype var1 = min(var0, 3.65f)`

But is there a way to define a literal, for instance like this:

`dtype var1 = min(var0, 3.65_dt)`

that can either be defined as float or double at compile time to ensure that also hard-coded numbers in the code will have the right precision?

Currently, I cast the number to `dtype` like this:

`dtype var1 = min(var0, (dtype)3.65)`

but I was concerned that this might create overhead in the case of single precision since the program might actually create a double precision number which is then cast to a single precision number. Is this indeed the case?

Comment: `constexpr dtype x = 3.65;` `x` will be calculated at compile time. But I would expect that to be the case with your code as well.

Comment: Macros really shouldn't be entering the scene at all. You should be able to express all of this with fairly straight forward templates

Comment: Concerning the literal: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a macro that appends an `f` suffix for `float`, as with `#define foo(x) x##f`, and does not for `double`, as with `#define foo(x) x`.

While you can also coerce constants to become `float` values with casts or various induced conversions, this creates a double-rounding process: The literal in source text is first converted to `double` and then converted to `float`. In about one instance in 2<sup>29</sup>, this produces a different result than if the literal is directly converted to `float`.

(2<sup>29</sup> is due to the difference in the numbers of bits in the significands of the formats commonly used for `float` and `double`, 24 and 53. This assumes a uniform distribution for the bit patterns in the representation. Practical data may have a different distribution.)